# Issue with NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Why Am I seeing different date formats below : see the output of select statement and output of anonymous block

```
13:46:23 13:46:23  SQL> conn prashant-mishra/ *****@*****

Connected to Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 

13:47:56 13:47:56  SQL> CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT SYSDATE as test_date 
                        FROM dual;
Table created


13:48:15 13:48:15  SQL> SELECT test_date FROM test;
                   TEST_DATE
                   -----------
                   **10/13/2016**

13:50:17 13:50:17  SQL> BEGIN
                   2    FOR rec IN (SELECT test_date FROM test) LOOP
                   3      dbms_output.put_line(rec.test_date);
                   4    END LOOP;
                   5  END;
                   6  /

**13-OCT-16**
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Other helpful info may be :

```
13:50:20 13:50:20  SQL> SELECT value FROM v$nls_parameters 
                        WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
            VALUE
            ----------------------------------------------------------------
            DD-MON-RR


13:50:45 13:50:45  SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;
            SYSDATE
            -----------
            **10/13/2016**
```

Comment: The anonymous block might use different NLS settings (implicit TO_CHAR conversion in dbms_output call) than the SQL*Plus session. Please check `nls_session_parameters` and `nls_database_parameters` for any differences that might explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk : I dont see any difference.                         select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT' ;--DD-MON-RR
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';--DD-MON-RR

Comment: What is the output of the anonymous block when you explicitly alter the session *before* execution with `alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR';` ?

Comment: Which data type got column `test_date`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it's DATE type

Answer (score 1):

SQL*Plus uses `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to format dates as strings so a complete test case needs to show what this parameter is beforehand. Would you please try the following and see if you get consistent formatting:

```
SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
DD-MON-RR

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
------------------
13-OCT-16

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
----------
2016-10-13

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
------------------
13-OCT-16

SQL>
```

You get the following output based on your comments:

```
SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
VALUE
DD-MON-RR

SQL> select sysdate from dual;
SYSDATE 
10/14/2016

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
Session altered

SQL> select sysdate from dual; 
SYSDATE
10/14/2016

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';
Session altered 

SQL> select sysdate from dual;
SYSDATE 
10/14/2016
```

So - SQLPlus is ignoring the session NLS_DATE_FORMAT and using it's only local format of `MM/DD/YYYY`. I didn't think there was a date format override in SQL*Plus but could be wrong. Have you tried the same commands in a different client?

Comment: 13:05:38 13:05:38  SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
VALUE
DD-MON-RR

13:05:50 13:05:50  SQL> select sysdate from dual;
SYSDATE
10/14/2016

13:05:56 13:05:56  SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
Session altered

13:06:04 13:06:04  SQL> select sysdate from dual;
SYSDATE
10/14/2016

13:06:08 13:06:08  SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';
Session altered

13:06:20 13:06:20  SQL> select sysdate from dual;
SYSDATE
10/14/2016